# Not receiving any Parse Push whatsoever

Tags: android, parse-platform, broadcastreceiver

I've followed every step outlined on Parse.com. I was first attempting to use a custom `BroadcastReceiver` (subclassing `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`), but even without so, Parse Push doesn't seem to work. Here is a look at my `AndroidManifest.xml` (snippet just before closing `<application>` tag):

```
<!-- For Parse Push -->
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
    android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="my.package.name" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
    android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

...and right before I open the `<application>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

I have tried pushing in all sorts of combinations, but absolutely no push seems to be going through.

All help greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: are you sure about `android:exported="false"`?

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for a quick response! I've written it just the way Parse does it on their tutorials/guide: https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for the pointer - the updated code in the QuickStart guide was missing this section and that pointed me to read it with greater detail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'll be arsed! Here's how I got it to work. First off, I switched to using the code in the `Parse Push QuickStart guide for Android` instead of an outdated tutorial by Parse. At the end of 4 wasted hours, I now see that an essential `WAKE_LOCK` permission is left out of the tutorial (Ikr?). (Presumably) More importantly, here's the change that seems to fix it, cerebral assassin as it may be - in your Application class:

```
public void onCreate() {
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
    Parse.initialize(this, "fo00", "b4r");
    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    super.onCreate(); // Moved this from right at the top, to right at the bottom
}
```